# Add loading html if data not loaded in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

We have many components in our app.
Some component required data from server then only it show html.
Until data doesn't come we need to show some loading bar html.

I am trying to figure out if there is any generic solution to this ?
I can start putting *ngIf inside each component but i am thinking more generic solution.

So currently I am thinking.

1. Create one Directive
2. Pass object inside directive
3. Check inside directive if object is available or not
4. If its not available then add some html inside element.

Till now below code is written.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomLoad]'
})
export class CustomLoadDirective implements AfterViewInit{

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
              private renderer: Renderer,
              private el: ElementRef) {

  }

  @Input() set appCustomLoad(shouldAdd: boolean){
    // currently i am passing boolean for testing,
    // if i use this solution then i will change boolean to any.
    // and if object is not null or undefined then we will show loading bar with some msg.
    if(shouldAdd){
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }else{
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // after view init
  }
}
```

I am not able to add html inside my div using directive.

I am **not sure is this correct way** to go so if you have any **better solution** then please give me **some idea**.

Comment: What does your component architecture look like? I'm guessing you could probably do your requests within your root component, and wrap whatever other component you need to hide with a single `ngIf`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy generic way of doing this but it's not so graceful. The solution is to create a service.loading variable that is gloabal:

```
 serviceTest.loading = 0;
```

Then inside your retrieval of data increase the amount by 1:

```
serviceTest.loading++;
```

Now you can create whatever loading animation you want

```
ng-if="serviceTest.loading > 0"
    //display loading gif
```

After the data is retrieved reduce the value by one

```
serviceTest.loading--;
```

The reason you use an integer rather than a boolean is because you want to support multiple retrievals.  Like that integer should go up to 3 and you don't want the loading to end until all 3 requests are finished.

Comment: thanks for reply. but may be i have not put question in proper way because 1. its angular 2 app. 2. if data doesnt come then i just want to add html instead of showing data inside div. 3. for just testing i have used boolean, but i will make that as any. as there can be any kind of object passed to directive.

Comment: Ok, so since you're using angular 2, the rootscope will change into a service, but the concept will still be the same.  I will update my answer.